# What are the pool node mining difficulty settings for darkcoin?

Tags: mining-pools, difficulty

What are the correct difficulty ssettings to mine darkcoin on a private pool node (pool side settings as shown below)?

```
"diff": 0   
"minDiff": 0
"maxDiff": 0
"targetTime": 0
"retargetTime": 0
"variancePercent": 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to  CryptoSiD

```
"diff": 0.00390625,
"varDiff": {
"minDiff": 0.00390625,
"maxDiff": 0.0078125,
"targetTime": 15,
"retargetTime": 150,
"variancePercent": 30
```

Comment: Could you maybe expand upon these settings?